# Parsing command line options using TSQL

Tags: sql-server, string, t-sql

I have a string which is a command line option. Let's say it's

> /server:server1.mydomain.com /username:user1 /password:"my password"
>   /other:"aa /bb \"cc"

I need to parse it using TSQL and get the following result:

```
+----------+----------------------+
| Key      | Value                |
+----------+----------------------+
| server   | server1.mydomain.com |
| username | user1                |
| password | my password          |
| other    | aa /bb "cc           |
+----------+----------------------+
```

I know TSQL is a database language and does not good at this kind of task. But I'm just thinking of its possibility. TSQL does not have built in regex support and it's hard to complete this task. Can anyone give it a try? Thanks.

```
DECLARE @options NVARCHAR(MAX);
SELECT @options = N'/server:server1.mydomain.com /username:user1 /password:"my password" /other:"aa /bb \"cc"';

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.store', N'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.store;
CREATE TABLE dbo.store
(
    key NVARCHAR(MAX),
    value NVARCHAR(MAX)
)

// This is the result I want
// +----------+----------------------+
// | Key      | Value                |
// +----------+----------------------+
// | server   | server1.mydomain.com |
// | username | user1                |
// | password | my password          |
// | other    | aa /bb "cc           |
// +----------+----------------------+
```

Comment: If the command line always looks the same it should be easy to parse using the substring and len functions. If I wasn't browsing on mobile I'd write it up for you :)

Comment: Thanks jpw. The command line is not fixed. The string in the code is just an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do something

```
USE [DEI]
GO
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[fnSplit]    Script Date: 07/06/2013 00:00:35 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
create FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplit](
   @sInputList VARCHAR(8000) -- List of delimited items
   , @sDelimiter VARCHAR(8000) = ',' -- delimiter that separates items
 ) RETURNS @List TABLE (item VARCHAR(8000))

BEGIN
DECLARE @sItem VARCHAR(8000)
WHILE CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,@sInputList,0) <> 0
 BEGIN
  SELECT
  @sItem=RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@sInputList,1,CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,@sInputList,0)-1))),
  @sInputList=RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@sInputList,CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,@sInputList,0)+LEN(@sDelimiter),LEN(@sInputList))))

IF LEN(@sItem) > 0
 INSERT INTO @List SELECT @sItem
END

IF LEN(@sInputList) > 0
INSERT INTO @List SELECT @sInputList -- Put the last item in
RETURN
END
```

then try following query :

```
DECLARE @options NVARCHAR(MAX);
SELECT @options = N'/server:server1.mydomain.com /username:user1 /password:"my password" /other:"aa /bb   \"cc"';


DECLARE @temp NVARCHAR(MAX);

set @temp = (SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@options,'/SERVER:' , '&&&&') , '/username:' ,  '&&&&'),'/password:' , '&&&&') , '/other:' , '&&&&'))

SELECT 
case 
when row_number() over(order by getdate()) = 1 then 'server' 
when row_number() over(order by getdate()) = 2 then 'username' 
when row_number() over(order by getdate()) = 3 then 'password' 
when row_number() over(order by getdate()) = 4 then 'other' 
end, *
FROM fnsplit(@temp , '&&&&') as a
```

Comment: Thanks Hiren for your answer. However, your solution depends on the fact that the option items are known in advance. Actually these information is now known beforehand.

Comment: The server, username, password etc. are just examples. The actually items are not fixed.

Comment: I thought that also but i have only one problem to make it dynamic is with /other:"aa /bb   \"cc" . otherwise i can split it with "/"

Comment: is there any way to quote that text ?

Comment: I don't think it can be quoted

Answer (score 0):

Try this

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9ef04/2)

```
DECLARE @options NVARCHAR(MAX)  = '/server:server1.mydomain.com /username:user1 /password:"my password" /other:"aa /bb \"cc"' 
    ,@str NVARCHAR(MAX)

WHILE LEN(@options) > 0
 BEGIN
    IF LEN(@options) - LEN(REPLACE(@options,':','')) >= 2
        BEGIN
            SELECT @str =  REVERSE(LEFT(@options, CHARINDEX(':', @options,CHARINDEX(':', @options)+ 1 )))
            SELECT @str = REVERSE(SUBSTRING(@str,CHARINDEX(' ',@str) + 1, LEN(@str)))
        END
     ELSE 
        SET @str = @options

    INSERT INTO store ([key],[value])
    SELECT --@str AS str
        SUBSTRING(@str, 2, CHARINDEX(':', @str) - 2 ) as [key]
        ,RIGHT(@str, LEN(@str) - CHARINDEX(':',@str)) as [value]
    SET  @options = LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@options,LEN(@str) + 1, LEN(@options))  )
 END

SELECT * from store
```

Comment: Thanks Eric for your answer. However your solution depends on the ":" in the string. If there are some ":"s in the string then your solution will break.